# Transpose T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transpose

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 

SUM(
     CASE 
   WHEN 
START_DATE <= '2014-01-01' AND 
(END_DATE > '2014-01-01' OR END_DATE IS NULL)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS '201401',

SUM(
     CASE 
   WHEN 
START_DATE <= '2014-02-01' AND 
(END_DATE > '2014-02-01' OR END_DATE IS NULL)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS '201402')

    (etc)

FROM table
```

Gives me this as output:

```
201401  201402   (etc)
485     498
```

I need this to be transposed, e.g. give me this output:

```
201401  485
201402  498
(etc)
```

Examples I've found are all grouping the data; I just need to swap row and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can transpose using union:

```
SELECT 
'201401',
SUM(
     CASE 
   WHEN 
START_DATE <= '2014-01-01' AND 
(END_DATE > '2014-01-01' OR END_DATE IS NULL)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM table

UNION ALL

SELECT 
'201402',
SUM(
     CASE 
   WHEN 
START_DATE <= '2014-02-01' AND 
(END_DATE > '2014-02-01' OR END_DATE IS NULL)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM table

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    (etc)
FROM table
```

Comment: Doesn't look elegant but gets the job done. Could've thought of it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `PIVOT`, but your column number must be finite and given like:

```
PIVOT
    (
        SUM (Indicator) FOR Day IN (  [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                    [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                    [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])
    ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do this on client's side. Not in Db.

```
SELECT fields, x FROM (
    -- {{ your query here
    select 485 as [201401], 498 as [201402]
    -- }} your query here
) AS t
UNPIVOT (
    x FOR fields in ([201401], [201402])
) AS unpvt
```